# How to implement the search text data in attached files in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, carrierwave, ransack

I have a requirement to search the text data in an attached file. I am currently using carrierwave for attachment and ransack for searching.

Is this feature available with what I am using? Or is there another way to satisfy my requirement?

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for a way to search data in attached files, such as pdfs, docs etc., I'd suggest using solr in conjunction with the sunspot and sunspot-cell gem.  More details on implementation in this blog post:

http://www.chebyte.com/2011/08/13/how-to-index-file-contents-like-pdf-doc-etc-with-solr-sunspot-paperclip-s3-and-rails-3/